# How to infer if $\frac{n x^s}{1+nx}$ increasing?

Tags: fractions, monotone-functions

How to infer IF $\frac{n x^s}{1+nx}$ increasing? It necessarily isn't, but I speculated it could be.

$0<s<1$, $n \rightarrow \infty$, $x \in [0,1]$.

I tried the derivative $f_n'(x)$ but it didn't seem conclusive.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous since you indicate two changing variables. Are you asking whether it is an increasing function of $x$ for each fixed value of $n$? Are you asking whether it is an increasing function of $n$ for each fixed value of $x$? I can't think of any other possible interpretation. There is no common meaning of "increasing" for a function of two variables that I'm aware of.

Comment: @MPW I agree with you. Moreover, it seems that this function depends also on $s$!

Comment: @the_candyman : Quite so! Even worse, if it could get worse!

Comment: @MPW Maybe this would suggest to not look for increasigness then.

Comment: As $n\to\infty$, the function behaves like $x^{s-1}$ which is decreasing for $x>0$ since $s-1<0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f'_n(x)=\frac{n x^{s-1 } (s - n x + n s x)}{(1 + n x)^2}
$$
Assuming $n$ is large enough so that $n(1-s)>1$ the derivative is positive when:
$$
0\le x< \frac{s}{n(1-s)} <1
$$
When $n$ increases this interval decreases.
For relatively small $n$ such that $n(1-s)<1$ :
$$
1\ge x>\frac{s}{n(1-s)}\gt0
$$

Note that as $ n\to\infty$, $\frac{s}{n(1-s)}$ becomes smaller and smaller.

Comment: So this is for all $x > 0$ then?

Comment: I added a comment. It will only hold for $x$ larger than the right hand side .

Comment: But how does it answer for $x \in [0,1]$ then?

Comment: The sign of $f'_n(x)$ then is the sign of $s-n(1-s)x$. For fixed $n$ and $s$, then $f_n$ is decreasing on $[0,\frac{s}{n(1-s)}]$ and increasing on $[\frac{s}{n(1-s)},1]$, assuming $\frac{s}{n(1-s)} \in(0,1)$.

Comment: I think there is an error in the final result. The inequality should be flipped.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I corrected it.

Comment: It still is incorrect. It should be $x<\frac s{n(1-s)}$

Comment: I also don't see where you get the $\frac{s}{n(1-s)}$

Answer (score 0):

As $n\to\infty,f_n(x)=\frac{x^s}{x+1/n}$ behaves like $f(x)=x^{s-1}~\forall x>0$. Since $s<1,f(x)$ is strictly decreasing for $x>0$.

[image]

Comment: This is really beautiful. Which app does that?

Comment: @am301 I graphed it in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and recorded my screen running the simulation. I think it can be done using Mathematica too.

Comment: Thanks much  - it is very instructive.